# Jump(seek) to markers in videojs on button click

Tags: reactjs, video.js

I have added markers to my videojs player. I want to jump to start time of every marker every time I click a particular button (say a next button). How should I do this. I know I have to change the currentTime but I am not getting how to solve the complete problem. I have start time of each marker. Any kind of input would be helpful. [image: Player]

Player.js

```
import assign from 'object-assign'
import cx from 'classnames'
import blacklist from 'blacklist'
import React from 'react'

module.exports = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'VideoJS',

  componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
      var player = videojs(this.refs.video, this.props.options).ready(function() {
          self.player = this;
          self.player.on('play', self.handlePlay);
      });

      if(this.props.onPlayerInit) this.props.onPlayerInit(player);

      player.markers({
          markerStyle: {},
          markers: [
              { startTime:10, endTime:15, time: 9.5, text: "compliance"},
              { startTime:20, endTime:25, time: 16,  text: "compliance"},
              { startTime:30, endTime:38, time: 23.6,text: "compliance"},
              { startTime:51, endTime:55, time: 28,  text: "compliance"}
          ]
      });


  },


  handlePlay: function() {
    if(this.props.onPlay) {
        this.props.onPlay(this.player);
    }
  },

  render() {
    var props = blacklist(this.props, 'children', 'className', 'src', 'type', 'onPlay');
    props.className = cx(this.props.className, 'videojs', 'video-js vjs-default-skin', 'vjs-big-play-centered');

    assign(props, {
      ref: 'video',
      controls: true
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <video {... props}>
          <source src={this.props.src} type={this.props.type}/>
        </video>
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

Marker.js

```
(function($, video, undefined) {
    //default setting
    var defaultSetting = {
        markerStyle: {
            'border-radius': '0%',
        },
        markerTip: {
            display: true,
            text: function(marker) {
                return "Break: "+ marker.text;
            },
            time: function(marker) {
                return marker.time;
            }
        },
        breakOverlay:{
            display: false,
            displayTime: 3,
            text: function(marker) {
                return "Break overlay: " + marker.overlayText;
            },
            style: {
                'width':'100%',
                'height': '20%',
                'background-color': 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)',
                'color': 'white',
                'font-size': '17px'
            }
        },
        onMarkerClick: function(marker) {},
        onMarkerReached: function(marker) {},
        markers: []
    };

    // create a non-colliding random number
    function generateUUID() {
        var d = new Date().getTime();
        var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
            var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
            d = Math.floor(d/16);
            return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
        });
        return uuid;
    };

    function registerVideoJsMarkersPlugin(options) {
        /**
         * register the markers plugin (dependent on jquery)
         */

        var setting      = $.extend(true, {}, defaultSetting, options),
            markersMap   = {},
            markersList  = [], // list of markers sorted by time
            videoWrapper = $(this.el()),
            currentMarkerIndex  = -1,
            player       = this,
            markerTip    = null,
            breakOverlay = null,
            overlayIndex = -1;

        function sortMarkersList() {
            // sort the list by time in asc order
            markersList.sort(function(a, b){
                return setting.markerTip.time(a) - setting.markerTip.time(b);
            });
        }

        function addMarkers(newMarkers) {
            // create the markers
            $.each(newMarkers, function(index, marker) {
                //console.log(index);
                // console.log(marker);
                marker.key = generateUUID();
                //console.log(marker.key);

                videoWrapper.find('.vjs-progress-control').append(
                    createMarkerDiv(marker));

                // store marker in an internal hash map
                markersMap[marker.key] = marker;
                console.log(markersMap);
                markersList.push(marker);

            });

            sortMarkersList();
        }

        function getPosition(marker){
            return (setting.markerTip.time(marker) / player.duration()) * 100
        }

        function createMarkerDiv(marker, duration) {
            var markerDiv = $("<div class='vjs-marker'></div>");
            console.log(marker.length);
            markerDiv.css(setting.markerStyle)
                .css({"margin-left" : -parseFloat(markerDiv.css("width"))/2 + 'px',
                    "left" : getPosition(marker) + '%', })
                .attr("data-marker-key", marker.key)
                .attr("data-marker-time", setting.markerTip.time(marker));
            console.log(setting.markerTip.time(marker));

            // add user-defined class to marker
            if (marker.class) {
                markerDiv.addClass(marker.class);
            }

            // bind click event to seek to marker time
            markerDiv.on('click', function(e) {

                var preventDefault = false;
                if (typeof setting.onMarkerClick === "function") {
                    // if return false, prevent default behavior
                    preventDefault = setting.onMarkerClick(marker) == false;
                }

                if (!preventDefault) {
                    var key = $(this).data('marker-key');
                    player.currentTime(setting.markerTip.time(markersMap[key]));
                }
            });

            if (setting.markerTip.display) {
                registerMarkerTipHandler(markerDiv);
            }

            return markerDiv;
        }
        function updateMarkers() {
            // update UI for markers whose time changed

            for (var i = 0; i< markersList.length; i++) {
                var marker = markersList[i];
                var markerDiv = videoWrapper.find(".vjs-marker[data-marker-key='" + marker.key +"']");
                var markerTime = setting.markerTip.time(marker);

                if (markerDiv.data('marker-time') != markerTime) {
                    markerDiv.css({"left": getPosition(marker) + '%'})
                        .attr("data-marker-time", markerTime);
                }
            }
            sortMarkersList();
        }

        function removeMarkers(indexArray) {
            // reset overlay
            if (breakOverlay){
                overlayIndex = -1;
                breakOverlay.css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            currentMarkerIndex = -1;

            for (var i = 0; i < indexArray.length; i++) {
                var index = indexArray[i];
                var marker = markersList[index];
                if (marker) {
                    // delete from memory
                    delete markersMap[marker.key];
                    markersList[index] = null;

                    // delete from dom
                    videoWrapper.find(".vjs-marker[data-marker-key='" + marker.key +"']").remove();
                }
            }

            // clean up array
            for (var i = markersList.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
                if (markersList[i] === null) {
                    markersList.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }

            // sort again
            sortMarkersList();
        }


        // attach hover event handler
        function registerMarkerTipHandler(markerDiv) {

            markerDiv.on('mouseover', function(){
                var marker = markersMap[$(this).data('marker-key')];

                markerTip.find('.vjs-tip-inner').text(setting.markerTip.text(marker));

                // margin-left needs to minus the padding length to align correctly with the marker
                markerTip.css({"left" : getPosition(marker) + '%',
                    "margin-left" : -parseFloat(markerTip.css("width"))/2 - 5 + 'px',
                    "visibility"  : "visible"});

            }).on('mouseout',function(){
                markerTip.css("visibility", "hidden");
            });
        }

        function initializeMarkerTip() {
            markerTip = $("<div class='vjs-tip'><div class='vjs-tip-arrow'></div><div class='vjs-tip-inner'></div></div>");
            videoWrapper.find('.vjs-progress-control').append(markerTip);
        }

        // show or hide break overlays
        function updateBreakOverlay() {
            if(!setting.breakOverlay.display || currentMarkerIndex < 0){
                return;
            }

            var currentTime = player.currentTime();
            var marker = markersList[currentMarkerIndex];
            var markerTime = setting.markerTip.time(marker);

            if (currentTime >= markerTime &&
                currentTime <= (markerTime + setting.breakOverlay.displayTime)) {
                if (overlayIndex != currentMarkerIndex){
                    overlayIndex = currentMarkerIndex;
                    breakOverlay.find('.vjs-break-overlay-text').html(setting.breakOverlay.text(marker));
                }

                breakOverlay.css('visibility', "visible");

            } else {
                overlayIndex = -1;
                breakOverlay.css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
        }

        // problem when the next marker is within the overlay display time from the previous marker
        function initializeOverlay() {
            breakOverlay = $("<div class='vjs-break-overlay'><div class='vjs-break-overlay-text'></div></div>")
                .css(setting.breakOverlay.style);
            videoWrapper.append(breakOverlay);
            overlayIndex = -1;
        }

        function onTimeUpdate() {
            onUpdateMarker();
            updateBreakOverlay();
        }

        function onUpdateMarker() {
            /*
             check marker reached in between markers
             the logic here is that it triggers a new marker reached event only if the player
             enters a new marker range (e.g. from marker 1 to marker 2). Thus, if player is on marker 1 and user clicked on marker 1 again, no new reached event is triggered)
             */

            var getNextMarkerTime = function(index) {
                if (index < markersList.length - 1) {
                    return setting.markerTip.time(markersList[index + 1]);
                }
                // next marker time of last marker would be end of video time
                return player.duration();
            }
            var currentTime = player.currentTime();
            var newMarkerIndex;

            if (currentMarkerIndex != -1) {
                // check if staying at same marker
                var nextMarkerTime = getNextMarkerTime(currentMarkerIndex);
                if(currentTime >= setting.markerTip.time(markersList[currentMarkerIndex]) &&
                    currentTime < nextMarkerTime) {
                    return;
                }

                // check for ending (at the end current time equals player duration)
                if (currentMarkerIndex === markersList.length -1 &&
                    currentTime === player.duration()) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            // check first marker, no marker is selected
            if (markersList.length > 0 &&
                currentTime < setting.markerTip.time(markersList[0])) {
                newMarkerIndex = -1;
            } else {
                // look for new index
                for (var i = 0; i < markersList.length; i++) {
                    nextMarkerTime = getNextMarkerTime(i);

                    if(currentTime >= setting.markerTip.time(markersList[i]) &&
                        currentTime < nextMarkerTime) {
                        newMarkerIndex = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            // set new marker index
            if (newMarkerIndex != currentMarkerIndex) {
                // trigger event
                if (newMarkerIndex != -1 && options.onMarkerReached) {
                    options.onMarkerReached(markersList[newMarkerIndex]);
                }
                currentMarkerIndex = newMarkerIndex;
            }

        }

        // setup the whole thing
        function initialize() {
            if (setting.markerTip.display) {
                initializeMarkerTip();
            }

            // remove existing markers if already initialized
            player.markers.removeAll();
            addMarkers(options.markers);

            if (setting.breakOverlay.display) {
                initializeOverlay();
            }
            onTimeUpdate();
            player.on("timeupdate", onTimeUpdate);
        }

        // setup the plugin after we loaded video's meta data
        player.on("loadedmetadata", function() {
            initialize();
        });

        // exposed plugin API
        player.markers = {
            getMarkers: function() {
                return markersList;
            },
            next : function() {
                // go to the next marker from current timestamp
                var currentTime = player.currentTime();
                for (var i = 0; i < markersList.length; i++) {
                    var markerTime = setting.markerTip.time(markersList[i]);
                    if (markerTime > currentTime) {
                        player.currentTime(markerTime);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            prev : function() {
                // go to previous marker
                var currentTime = player.currentTime();
                for (var i = markersList.length - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
                    var markerTime = setting.markerTip.time(markersList[i]);
                    // add a threshold
                    if (markerTime + 0.5 < currentTime) {
                        player.currentTime(markerTime);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            },
            add : function(newMarkers) {
                // add new markers given an array of index
                addMarkers(newMarkers);
            },
            remove: function(indexArray) {
                // remove markers given an array of index
                removeMarkers(indexArray);
            },
            removeAll: function(){
                var indexArray = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < markersList.length; i++) {
                    indexArray.push(i);
                }
                removeMarkers(indexArray);
            },
            updateTime: function(){
                // notify the plugin to update the UI for changes in marker times
                updateMarkers();
            },
            reset: function(newMarkers){
                // remove all the existing markers and add new ones
                player.markers.removeAll();
                addMarkers(newMarkers);
            },
            destroy: function(){
                // unregister the plugins and clean up even handlers
                player.markers.removeAll();
                breakOverlay.remove();
                markerTip.remove();
                player.off("timeupdate", updateBreakOverlay);
                delete player.markers;
            },
        };
    }

    videojs.plugin('markers', registerVideoJsMarkersPlugin);

})(jQuery, window.videojs);
```

Comment: post your current code.

Comment: @HusseinAlkaf Check my edits

Comment: @ApurvG hey, did you figured it out? Doing the same thing right now.